# Python: "Cannot import flask"

Tags: python, flask, pip, cs50

I tried everything but couldn't import app.py. It gives me the following error

```
set FLASK_APP = "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\sakshi.py\app.py"

(env) C:\Users\Hp\Documents\flask_app>flask run

Serving Flask app " app.py"
Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Error: Could not import " app".
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you show us your code

Comment: ... and the error you got. We need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sever environment to development env.

```
 export FLASK_APP=yourapp
 export FLASK_ENV=development
```

and then start the server with:

```
 flask run
```

If you still get error try this way:

```
set FLASK_ENV=development

flask run
```

And then run your python file.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem: spaces in the `set` command. From the syntax in the [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1):

```
set [<Variable>=[<String>]]
set [/p] <Variable>=[<PromptString>]
set /a <Variable>=<Expression>
```

There is no space on either side of the `=` in the set command.

And, the path name `"C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\sakshi.py\app.py"` is questionable. It is, at the very least, a bad idea to name a directory `sakshi.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I could see the problem is with space between the variable and value in `set` command,

In windows,

```
set var=value
```

In *nix family,

```
export var=value
```

Your script name is `app.py` which by default flask recognizes as entry point for the app.

You only have to explicitly set the `FLASK_APP` variable when you are running from another directory (which you are) or the name of the script is something other than `app.py`. You can directly run the `flask run` command from the project base directory itself.